# How much memory w3wp.exe consume

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have 32 gb ram on my server, And my w3wp.exe process crashes when it reaches around 1gb of memory. I monitored it through task manager. It is a 64 bit machine

(Browser Requests are not responded when it reaches 1gb  and application pool gets recycled)

My question

Is there any memory limit for w3wp.exe process ?

If i increase the physical memory in Application pool to use 8gb of ram will it work?

Comment: Can you include the service exception information? This should be in your windows application log.

Comment: Voting to move to Server Fault.

Comment: Derrick: Browser Requests are not responded when it reaches 1gb  and application pool gets recycled

Comment: Definitely no standard limit. We run w3wp processes well over 10gb without issue.

Comment: @Rex : Did you modify any app pool setting?

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software, particularly McAfee enterprise v8 ?

Comment: May be, Need to check, Will it cause any problem ?

Comment: I am not sure, I just found http://forums.iis.net/t/1150494.aspx and there is "It turns out the virus checker we had installed (McAfee enterprise v8) had a new buffer overflow protection feature that causes problems with w3wp.exe"

Answer (score 1):

If the app pool is recycling due to a particular amount of memory being used, in the advanced app pool settings, check the 'Recycling' section.  Be sure that 'Private Memory Limit' is set to zero to indicate there is no memory limit for the app pool before it recycles.  You'll want to do the same for 'Virtual Memory Limit'.

Event IDs in the event log should tell you why an app pool recycled.  Here is some additional info on those event codes:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735206%28WS.10%29.aspx